# Prevent php injection

Tags: php, code-injection

im looking for all the ways to prevent people from entering php code into text field at the php level. i have prevention from sql injection but do i not need a way to prevent people from say messing with my if statements?

```
$email=$_POST["email"];
if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
{
    //do suff
}
```

can a user not enter something like "not@a@valid@email.com = valid@email.com" as the email and it will be considered valid.
I know this example isn't bad for the server but i'm sure others and come up with more deadly.

Or am i worrying about something that is never a problem?

Comment: PHP doesn't execute variables as code unless you call `eval()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a problem, since the user data is the *value of a string*. It's no different from saying:

```
filter_var("die()", FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)
```

That also doesn't kill your program. It's just text.

Just don't use [`eval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php). Not ever, but specifically not ever on user input.

Comment: Oh i understand now sql needs the be prepared because it is a string statement but php differs code from being a string thank you